# Error en retrasar ocultar mensaje mediante delay & fadeOut - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo la siguiente línea que me emite un mensaje de éxito mediante un `div`, pero algunas penas alcanzo leer el mensaje.

```
$('.message').html(textStatus).delay(60000).fadeOut(60000);
location.href = 'exito.php';},60000);
```

A diferencia de `location.href = 'exito.php';},60000);`
 que redirecciona en un minuto.

Agrego el mismo valor:

`$('.message').html(textStatus).delay(60000).fadeOut(60000);`

Pero el mensaje se oculta en menos de 7 segundos.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el retraso que se desaparezca el mensaje por 30 segundos o aun minuto? Al igual que el `location` que sí funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Mira puedes usar algo como esto

```js
$('#Mensaje').html("HOLA"); //SETEO EL TEXTO EN EL OBJETO
setTimeout(function(){ //INICIO UN RELOJ DE 3 SEGUNDOS
    $('#Mensaje').fadeOut("fast"); //OCULTO EL MENSAJE
},3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Mensaje"><div>
```

Mas info `setTimeout` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

El Valor **3000** Son los segundos = 3

**30000** Serian los 30 segundos

Aunque haciendo pruebas tu código también funciona bien, en este ejemplo espera 30 segundos para ocultar el mensaje

```js
$(".Mensaje")
.html("HOLA") //SETEO EL HTML
.delay(30000) //ESPERO 30 SEGUNDOS
.fadeOut("fast"); //OCULTO
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Mensaje"></div>
```

Mas info `delay` https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Mas info `fadeout` http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

También te dejo un ejemplo con el que puedes jugar un poco con el tiempo

```js
var segundos=0;
function Contador(){
    $("#Contador").text(segundos/1000);
    if(segundos>0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            segundos-=1000;
            Contador();
        },1000);
    }else{
     $("#Contador").text("");
    }
}
$("#Iniciar").click(function(){
    segundos=$("#Tiempo").val();
    var rs=segundos;
    Contador();
 $(".Mensaje").show()
        .html("HOLA")
        .delay(rs)
        .fadeOut("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="Tiempo" placeholder="Tiempo" value="3000">
<button id="Iniciar">Iniciar conteo para ocultar</button>
<div id="Contador"></div>
<div class="Mensaje"></div>
```

Saludos :)

Comment: Hola, y el `.delay()` para que sirve?

Comment: @RuberHernandez De esta manera no funciona `.delay(60000).fadeOut(60000);` el procedimiento realizado que ocasiona, porque desaparece en menos de 7 segundos.

Comment: Si te fijas en el segundo snippet si lo hace correctamente, voy a cambiar el tiempo a 30 segundos para ver el efecto, en el tiempo de desaparición también pones 1 minuto; tardara 1 minuto en desvanecer el texto aparte del minuto que pones del delay **fadeOut(60000);**

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, por mi parte te acreditare la recompensa :) esperemos el SO, valide su respuesta como correcta, Saludos :)